# How to hide gwt-dialog box border completely?

Tags: gwt

How could I hide border of dialog box in GWT completely or we can say that hide the dialog box's caption portion completely.  I tried to use .gwt-DialogBox .Caption {} in css
but I couldn't find any option which could hide the border fully.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `gwt-DialogBox` name for css to change dialog box. it will not apply. try to apply different style name with same style like:

```
.gwt-DialogBoxNew
{
    border: 8px solid #7F7F7F;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    line-height: 7px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color : #FFFFFF;
}

.gwt-DialogBoxNew .Caption {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
    border: medium none #D4D4D4;
    cursor: default;
    font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial, sans-serif !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 27px;
    padding:2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogContent {
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogMiddleCenter {
  padding: 3px;
  background: white;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogBottomCenter {

}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogMiddleLeft {
/*   background: url(images/vborder.png) repeat-y -31px 0px; */

}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogMiddleRight {
 /*  background: url(images/vborder.png) repeat-y -32px 0px;


}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogTopLeftInner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 8px;
  zoom: 1;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogTopRightInner {
  width: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogBottomLeftInner {
  width: 10px;
  height: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogBottomRightInner {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  zoom: 1;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogTopLeft {
 /*  background: url(images/circles.png) no-repeat -20px 0px;
  -background: url(images/circles_ie6.png) no-repeat -20px 0px; */
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogTopRight {
/*   background: url(images/circles.png) no-repeat -28px 0px;
  -background: url(images/circles_ie6.png) no-repeat -28px 0px; */
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E4E4E4;
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogBottomLeft {
/*   background: url(images/circles.png) no-repeat 0px -36px;
  -background: url(images/circles_ie6.png) no-repeat 0px -36px; */
}
.gwt-DialogBoxNew .dialogBottomRight {
/*   background: url(images/circles.png) no-repeat -8px -36px;
  -background: url(images/circles_ie6.png) no-repeat -8px -36px; */
}
```

Remove border style from it as you concern here.

Comment: ok i will do that. All the options above I had tried but no one could set caption and border of gwt dialog box to none. Could you please tell the option for this purpose.

Comment: Remove use of `setText` property for set caption in dialogbox. and for remove border apply `border:0px !important`.

Comment: I am not using it. There is a sample image in this link http://static1.hivedevelopment.co.uk/blog/gwt-best-practise-mvp-di-command/after.png. I want this blue border hidden. So that I could have a plane rectangle.

Comment: can you add some code? Remove border apply from style. as I mention apply style like `dialogBox.setStyleName("gwt-DialogBoxNew")`. don't use `gwt-DialogBox`. clear cache. and check.

Comment: Yes now its working. Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how could I draw a rectangle around my dialog box.

Comment: gr8 :) Accept this answer. and make habit to ask new question for new problem for other attention and other will help you.

Answer (score 1):

A `DialogBox` is basically a `DecoratedPopupPanel` with a *caption*. You want neither the *decoration* nor the *caption*, so how about using a `PopupPanel` instead? (AFAICT, the only difference will be how you size the panel)